# Typo3 Fluid - Responsive image viewhelper

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In my extension I'm using the Typo3 image manipulation. I would like to render the picture responsive with the srcset attribute. Therefore I'm using the VHS media.image viewhelper. The problem I have is that this viewhelper doesn't support the Typo3 native crop functionality. And the Fluid image viewhelper doesn't support the srcset functionality.

Is there a easy solution for this problem or do I need to write a custom viewhelper?

```
<f:image treatIdAsReference="true" src="{image.id}" alt="{image.alternative}" title="{image.title}" crop="{image.crop}" />

<v:media.image src="{image.id}" alt="{image.alternative}" title="{image.title}" srcset="480,768,992,1200" />
```

I'm happy for every help.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not yet implemented in VHS. I just created a pull request which can be found at https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/pull/1091/commits/761435c82786cf9da6626d849a39c6a9124bfdff.

Just override the related file and it should be fine!

Comment: the Change has been merged FYI

Comment: When I'm using the crop feature, the srcset pictures don't get generated. The image gets cropped, but the smaller images are missing.

Comment: If treatIdAsReference="true" the crop feature is not working.

Comment: After debugging the code I found out that there is a problem with $this->contentObject->getImgResource in the SourceSetViewHelperTrait.php

The function does not work on processed images. I have the same problem if I change the quality.

Comment: Can you please open an issue at the github repository? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed the SourceSetViewHelperTrait.php. Now the rendering is working. treatIdAsReference must be true otherwise the processed image will be used to create the srcset images.

```
<?php
namespace FluidTYPO3\Vhs\Traits;

use FluidTYPO3\Vhs\Utility\FrontendSimulationUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\MathUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface;

/*
 * This file is part of the FluidTYPO3/Vhs project under GPLv2 or later.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE.md file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

/**
 * This trait can be used by viewhelpers that generate image tags
 * to add srcsets based to the imagetag for better responsiveness
 */
trait SourceSetViewHelperTrait
{

    /**
     * used to attach srcset variants of a given image to the specified tag
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\TagBuilder $tag the tag to add the srcset as argument
     * @param string $src image path to render srcsets for
     * @return array
     */
    public function addSourceSet($tag, $src)
    {
        $srcsets = $this->getSourceSetWidths();

        if ('BE' === TYPO3_MODE) {
            FrontendSimulationUtility::simulateFrontendEnvironment();
        }

        $width = $this->arguments['width'];
        $height = $this->arguments['height'];
        $format = $this->arguments['format'];
        $quality = $this->arguments['quality'];
        $dimensions = [
            'ratio'=>0,
        ];
        $treatIdAsReference = (boolean) $this->arguments['treatIdAsReference'];
        if (true === $treatIdAsReference) {
            $src = $this->arguments['src'];
            $crop = $this->arguments['crop'];
            if ($crop === null) {
                $crop = $src instanceof FileReference ? $src->getProperty('crop') : null;
            }
            $dimensions = $this->getDimensions($width, $height);
        }


        $imageSources = [];
        $srcsetVariants = [];

        foreach ($srcsets as $key => $width) {
            if (0 < $dimensions['ratio']) {
                $height = floor((int)$width/$dimensions['ratio']) . $dimensions['postHeight'];
            }

            $width = $width . $dimensions['postWidth'];
            $srcsetVariant = $this->getImgResource($src, $width, $height, $format, $quality, $treatIdAsReference, $crop);

            $srcsetVariantSrc = rawurldecode($srcsetVariant[3]);
            $srcsetVariantSrc = $this->preprocessSourceUri(GeneralUtility::rawUrlEncodeFP($srcsetVariantSrc));

            $imageSources[$srcsetVariant[0]] = [
                'src' => $srcsetVariantSrc,
                'width' => $srcsetVariant[0],
                'height' => $srcsetVariant[1],
            ];
            $srcsetVariants[$srcsetVariant[0]] = $srcsetVariantSrc . ' ' . $srcsetVariant[0] . 'w';
        }

        $tag->addAttribute('srcset', implode(',', $srcsetVariants));

        if ('BE' === TYPO3_MODE) {
            FrontendSimulationUtility::resetFrontendEnvironment();
        }

        return $imageSources;
    }

    /**
     * generates a copy of a give image with a specific width
     *
     * @param string $src path of the image to convert
     * @param integer $width width to convert the image to
     * @param integer $height height to convert the image to
     * @param string $format format of the resulting copy
     * @param string $quality quality of the resulting copy
     * @param string $treatIdAsReference given src argument is a sys_file_reference record
     * @param string $crop image crop string
     * @param array $params additional params for the image rendering
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImgResource($src, $width, $height, $format, $quality, $treatIdAsReference, $crop, $params = null)
    {

        $setup = [
            'width' => $width,
            'height' => $height,
            'treatIdAsReference' => $treatIdAsReference,
            'crop' => $crop,
        ];
        if (false === empty($format)) {
            $setup['ext'] = $format;
        }
        if (0 < intval($quality)) {
            $quality = MathUtility::forceIntegerInRange($quality, 10, 100, 75);
            $setup['params'] .= ' -quality ' . $quality;
        }

        if ('BE' === TYPO3_MODE && '../' === substr($src, 0, 3)) {
            $src = substr($src, 3);
        }
        return $this->contentObject->getImgResource($src, $setup);
    }

    /**
     * returns an array of srcsets based on the mixed ViewHelper
     * input (list, csv, array, iterator)
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSourceSetWidths()
    {
        $srcsets = $this->arguments['srcset'];
        if (true === $srcsets instanceof \Traversable) {
            $srcsets = iterator_to_array($srcsets);
        } elseif (true === is_string($srcsets)) {
            $srcsets = GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', $srcsets, true);
        } else {
            $srcsets = (array) $srcsets;
        }
        return $srcsets;
    }

    private function getDimensions($width, $height)
    {
        $widthSplit = [];
        $heightSplit = [];
        if (false === empty($width)) {
            preg_match("/(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)/", $width, $widthSplit);
        }

        if (false === empty($height)) {
            preg_match("/(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)/", $height, $heightSplit);
        }

        $dimensions = [
            'width'=>(int)$widthSplit[1],
            'height'=>(int)$heightSplit[1],
            'postWidth'=>$widthSplit[2],
            'postHeight'=>$heightSplit[2],
            'ratio'=> 0,
        ];
        if (0 < $dimensions['height']) {
            $dimensions['ratio'] = $dimensions['width']/$dimensions['height'];
        }
        return $dimensions;
    }
}
```